# Using awk to put a header in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cat

I have lots of text files and need to put a header on each one of them depending of the data on each file.

This awk command accomplishes the task:

```
awk 'NR==1{first=$1}{sum+=$1;}END{last=$1;print NR,last,"L";}' my_text.file
```

But this prints it on the screen and I want to put this output in the header of each of my file, and saving the modifications with the same file name.

Here is what I've tried:

```
for i in *.txt
do
echo Processing ${i}
cat awk 'NR==1{first=$1}{sum+=$1;}END{last=$1;print NR,last,"L";}' "${i}" ${i} > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp "${i}"
done
```

So I guess I can't use cat to put them as a header, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty related: http://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: This could be simplier using `perl` with `-i` flag!

Comment: Try to replace 4th line with: `awk 'NR==1{first=$1}{sum+=$1;}END{last=$1;print NR,last,"L";}' < "${i}"`  (whipe the `cat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK what you're trying to do with your loop is:

```
for i in *.txt
do
    echo "Processing $i"
    awk 'NR==1{first=$1}{sum+=$1}END{last=$1;print NR,last,"L"}' "$i" > $$.tmp &&
    cat "$i" >> $$.tmp &&
    mv $$.tmp "$i"
done
```

but it's not clear what you're really trying to do since you never use `first` or `sum` and setting `last` in the END section is a bad idea as it will not work across all awks and there's a simple alternative.

If you update your question with some sample input and expected output we can help you.

Comment: is there a way to avoid all those temp files being generated?

Comment: There's only 1 temp file generated. With the script above you could simply add a close(FILENAME) and then do your prints > FILENAME but that script makes no sense so it can't be what you're really doing. Without knowing what you're really doing it's tough to give you a good answer. Newer releases of GNU awk have `-i inplace` option that MIGHT be what you want but there might be better alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "header"}1' test.txt
```

without `awk`:

with `cat` & `echo`:

```
cat <(echo "header") test.txt
```

(OR)

using `tac`:

```
tac test.txt | echo "header" >> test.txt | tac test.txt
```