# How to add a header to awk output?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a csv file that looks like below

```
"10.8.70.67","wireless",,"UTY_07_ISD",,26579
"10.8.70.69","wireless",,"RGB_34_FTR",,19780
```

I want to retrieve first, second and fourth column values (without quotes) and populate into a another csv in the below format.

```
IP          DEVICETYPE  DEVICENAME
10.8.70.67  wireless    UTY_07_ISD
10.8.70.69  wireless    RGB_34_FTR
```

I have used the below awk command

```
awk -F ',|,,' '{gsub(/"/,"",$1); gsub(/"/,"",$2); gsub(/"/,"",$3); print $1, $2, $3}' file.csv
```

and got the below output

```
10.8.70.67  wireless    UTY_07_ISD
10.8.70.69  wireless    RGB_34_FTR
```

please help in assigning headings to each column.

Comment: @tink, IMHO, this doesn't look like a dupe for this question.

Comment: Your desired output is not CSV at all. Please clarify; do you actually want an answer for CSV (in which case the duplicate is correct) or for fixed-width space-separated columns?

Comment: `Hi, I am able to get the required output. I just want to add heading to each column.` OP has given this comment in my answer's section by which I am thinking that OP may not needed a csv file in output but lets wait for OP to come back here, though I will still say it was too early to make this dupe, once OP confirms about it and dupe link is working fine for him then its certainly a dupe.

Comment: I have re-opened the question, by seeing OP's comments on answer section `Hi, I am able to get the required output. I just want to add heading to each column.`(for which it doesn't look like correct dupe) if in case OP confirms on tripleee's above comments then will vote to make it dupe, thank you.

Comment: Though still not sure, if in case OP needs comma in output, just fyi here; got sometime to check all answers on dupe link which was proposed and doesn't look to be right for shown samples, since OP's samples are having `"` too in it, they simply add headers to file which is not needed here, thank you.

Comment: He had his desired all but the header; the 2nd answer to the question I pointed out as dupe clearly showed how to do that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852630/using-awk-to-put-a-header-in-a-text-file

Comment: @tink, Hello tink, I could see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216107/adding-column-headers-in-csv-with-awk-in-terminal this link from history which is completely different from which you are sharing now. So I have checked this link. Also OP's approach towards solving this problem doesn't look good here, so approaches given here will help to make that part efficient also along with only adding headers IMHO.

Comment: I'm not going to lose sleep over this; I fail to see how them using a `BEGIN{print "header" }` differs from yours. Never mind the small differences in the processing.  My understanding was that [so] is here to answer broader questions, not necessarily each individuals request to the point. I'm not saying your answer isn't good - I just don't think it's necessary.

Answer (score 5):

assuming you don't have comma or double quotes in the quoted strings (a big assumption!) it can be as simple as

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 {print "IP","DEVICETYPE","DEVICENAME"} 
                 {gsub(/"/,""); 
                  print $1,$2,$4}' file | column -t

IP          DEVICETYPE  DEVICENAME
10.8.70.67  wireless    UTY_07_ISD
10.8.70.69  wireless    RGB_34_FTR
```

Comment: I got the output with the command

awk -F ',|,,' 'BEGIN {print "IP,DEVICETYPE,DEVICENAME"} {gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/"/, "", $2); gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $1","$2","$3}' input.csv > output.csv

I found that I was missing BEGIN part. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @selvanvenkatesh Note that `BEGIN` will print the header even if the input file is empty. The other alternative will only add header if there is at least one line in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  print "IP          DEVICETYPE  DEVICENAME"
}
function remove(fields){
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$arr[i])
  }
}
{
  remove("1,2,4")
  print $1,$2,$4
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")' '    ##Setting FPAT to get only matched fields only as ([^,]*)|("[^"]+") as per samples.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  print "IP          DEVICETYPE  DEVICENAME" ##printing header here.
}
function remove(fields){             ##Creating function named remove here where we are passing field numbers from where we need to remove "
  num=split(fields,arr,",")          ##Splitting fields into arr here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){               ##Traversing through all items of arr here.
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$arr[i])         ##Globally substituting starting and ending " in mentioned fields with NULL here.
  }
}
{
  remove("1,2,4")                    ##Calling remove here with field numbers of 1,2 and 4 which we need as per output.
  print $1,$2,$4                     ##Printing 1st, 2nd and 4th field here.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to get the required output. I just want to add heading to each column.

Comment: @selvanvenkatesh, sure, I have edited my code now, kindly check it once and let me know how it goes? cheers.

Comment: @selvanvenkatesh, could you please reply on tripleee's comment in question section(where its being asked if you need a csv file or not in output) and confirm if attached link for duplicate question helping you or not, thank you.

Comment: I got the output with the command

awk -F ',|,,' 'BEGIN {print "IP,DEVICETYPE,DEVICENAME"} {gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/"/, "", $2); gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $1","$2","$3}' input.csv > output.csv

I found that I was missing BEGIN part. Thanks Ravinder for your response.

Comment: @selvanvenkatesh, you didn't answer my previous comment, do you need commas in your expected output? Because your samples of output doesn't show that? Kindly do confirm on same once.

Comment: @selvanvenkatesh, in case you need `,` comma separated output without `"` present like your shown output then I have added `OFS=","` in my code now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple oneliner will be:

```
awk -F ',|,,' 'BEGIN {format = "%-20s %-20s %-20s\n"; printf format, "IP", "DEVICETYPE", "DEVICENAME"} {gsub(/"/,"",$1); gsub(/"/,"",$2); gsub(/"/,"",$3); printf format, $1, $2, $3}' abc.csv
```

Here I have used BEGIN/END special pattern, which is used to do some startup or cleanup actionn, to add headings. For more details please refer to the documentation [Using BEGIN/END](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGIN_002fEND.html)

Comment: I got the output with the command

awk -F ',|,,' 'BEGIN {print "IP,DEVICETYPE,DEVICENAME"} {gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/"/, "", $2); gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $1","$2","$3}' input.csv > output.csv

I found that I was missing BEGIN part. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -2):

I got the expected output with the below command

awk -F ',|,,' 'BEGIN {print "IP,DEVICETYPE,DEVICENAME"} {gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/"/, "", $2); gsub(/"/, "", $3); print $1","$2","$3}' input.csv > output.csv

I found that I was missing BEGIN part. Thanks all for your response.